# Only Xcom or data flow python operator?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, airflow

Hi im using Airflow S3List operator

```
response_table_parquet_list = S3ListOperator(
    task_id = 'get_bucket_object_list_operator',
    aws_conn_id = 'cloudFlare_conn',
    bucket = 'paprika-table-storage',
    prefix = 'response_table/',
    dag = dag,
)
```

So blob my file list
But how to return after task??

All operator except python operator cannot return data or Xcom?

Already Using xcom_pull(task_ids='response_table_parquet_list') But None

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong id when calling xcom_pull. response_table_parquet_list is the variable name that you assigned the operator to, the actual task id is get_bucket_object_list_operator